# Is there a way to assert file is not empty in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, file, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am writing a unit a test for a method which is supposed to be able to locate a file and write to it. PHPUnit has methods to compare two files, whether it exists or not, however I am not able to find any method to check if the file is non empty, or even better is there a method if file size and updated timestamp can be asserted ?

P.S. I know how to do this using php in-built filesize function. I Just want to know if it is possible in PHPUnit

Comment: You should really be mocking the file system using something like [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/)

Comment: thanks this is kind of tool i was looking for

Comment: `$this->assertNotEquals("", $yourString);`

Answer (score 7):

For checking if file is not empty you can use this phpunit method:

```
$this->assertStringNotEqualsFile('/tmp/file', '');
```